# Play 2 + scala-activerecord edit associated entities in forms

Tags: forms, scala, activerecord, playframework-2.0

It seems like it's not possible to edit associated entities with scala-activerecord and play 2.

```
case class User(name: String) extends ActiveRecord {
    lazy val car = hasOne[Car]
}
case class Car(name: String) extends ActiveRecord {
   lazy val user = belongsTo[User]
}
// companion objects
```

I would like to edit a user's car in the user form. Now I have to create 2 forms(userForm and carForm) and handle them separetely.

Do you know a good solution for this? I already filed a feature request here (https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord/issues/36) but suggestions for a better solution are welcome.